# How to bind property of a ObservableCollection in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a ChatroomViewModel:

```
//ObservableObject implements INotifyPropertyChanged
public class ChatroomViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<Chat> _chatCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<Chat> ChatCollection
    {
        get { return this._chatCollection;  }
        set
        {
            if (null != value)
            {
                this._chatCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ChatCollection");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ChatroomView:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ChatCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Name: "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChatCollection.Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Created by: "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ChatCollection.CreatedBy}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This is the ChatModel:

```
//ObservableDatabaseModel also implements INotifyPropertyChanged
public class Chat : ObservableDatabaseModel
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name 
    {
        get { return this._name; }
        set
        {
            this._name = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    private string _createdBy;        
    public string CreatedBy 
    {
        get { return this._createdBy; }
        set
        {
            this._createdBy = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("CreatedBy");
        }
    }
}
```

The binding works but it just show the location of the object, instead of the specified Name/Createdby property text.

I have no idea why this isn't working, I used `ObservableCollection<Chat>` instead of `List<Chat>` because it can bind its property too, I have also implemented INotifyPropertyChanged to the "sub-class": Chat.

I'm not using any extra MVVM framework, so I can't do much with a MVVM-light solution or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`DataContext`](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/) of the UI elements inside the [`ListBoxItem`](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/03/25/itemscontrol-i-is-for-item-container/)s is already an instance of your `Chat` class.

WPF automatically assigns the `DataContext` of the `ListBoxItem` and all it's contents to the corresponding instance of the *Data Item*.

Therefore your bindings should be like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="Name: "/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
<TextBlock Text="Created by: "/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CreatedBy}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The data context in your data template is an item.

Try this:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ChatCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Name: "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Created by: "/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CreatedBy}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</List
```

Notice that I removed 'ChatCollection.' from the bindings.